# Perfect or minimal hash for Type arrays?

Tags: c#, arrays, dictionary, types, hash

Is there a pure and minimal hash for `Type[]` in C# ?

I have a lot of places in hotspots where I map a `Type[]` to a object like this and access it for a lookup: `Dictionary<Type[], object>` however since I only have a few items in it, its incredible slow and does not make sense for my use case.

Thus I thought about using a lookup array table, however this would mean I would need to convert the `Type[]` to a low value starting at 1 e.g. and increasing it with every new `Type[]`.

```
Type[SomeStruct, SomeClass] : 1 -> object
Type[OtherStruct, OtherClass] : 2 -> object
Type[SomeClass, OtherStruct] : 3 -> object
...
```

The problem is that I do not know which types are used, neither which `Type[]` in the end, so I can not really register them or static compile them.

What else could I do to efficiently map a `Type[]` to a object in the fastest way possible ? And do such a minimal hash or perfect hash function exist for `Type[]` ?

Comment: There can't possibly be; `Type` is open-ended. They can even be generated at runtime. If you're only interested in hashing primitive types `TypeCode` can be used. A `TypeCode`-like construct can be used for your own types as well (as you've pointed out). For a sufficiently limited number of possible types and combinations you can cut up the 64 bits of a `long` into pieces as a quick hash key.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Thanks ! That makes sense and... sucks. In this case hashing wont help me, what else could i do to map a `Type[]` to a `object` in an efficient way ?

Comment: If both the number of types and the size of the array itself are in principle unbounded there's not a whole lot you can do to make it optimal. But I suspect that in practice you can put reasonable bounds on either one. To a first approximation a simple way would be to just `string.Join('|', ...`) the type names together and use that as your key. If there are lots of combinations this consumes quite a bit of memory, but premature optimization is the root of all evil after all. The next obvious thing to explore would be a custom type instead of `Type[]` for representing the collection.